# Listview item not being displayed

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, listviewitem

I am having trouble determining why my data is not being displayed.  Here is my xaml.cs file.  I left off the references as it compiles and runs fine.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] firstRecord = new string[3] {"1", "2", "3"};
        listview1.Items.Add(firstRecord);

    }
}
```

Here is the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="listview1">

        <ListView.View>

            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true"
          ColumnHeaderToolTip="Employee Information">

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                      "{Binding Path=listview1.Items[0]}" 
                  Header="Column1" Width="100"/>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                      "{Binding Path=listview1.Items[1]}" 
                  Header ="2nd Column" Width="100">
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                      "{Binding Path=listview1.Items[2]}" 
                  Header="3rd Column" Width="100"/>
            </GridView>

        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: have you tried changing the ListView name = to this `<ListView x:Name="listview1" />` also the `listview1.ItemSource = firstRecord;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have added an `Array` to the `ListView` your `Column` bindings only need to be the index you want

```
<ListView Name="listview1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Employee Information">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[0]}" Header="Column1" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[1]}" Header ="2nd Column" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[2]}" Header="3rd Column" Width="100"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Result:

[image]

### Use DataBinding

**However**, you should be using `DataBinding` to your `ListView` as it is bad practice to access `UI` controls in code in `WPF`.

Here is an example of proper binding of your String Arrays

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=Records}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Employee Information">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[0]}" Header="Column1" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[1]}" Header ="2nd Column" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=[2]}" Header="3rd Column" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Records.Add(new string[3] { "1", "2", "3" });
        Records.Add(new string[3] { "10", "20", "30" });
        Records.Add(new string[3] { "100", "200", "300" });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string[]> _records = new ObservableCollection<string[]>();
    public ObservableCollection<string[]> Records
    {
        get { return _records; }
        set { _records = value; }
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Interesting I have never seen binding on an array like that +1

Comment: Thanks for help sa_dadam213.  Thanks for going the extra mile to explain the best practice as well.

Answer (score 1):

Listviews aren't going to give you very good results using a string array.  I would create an object and bind to that, something like this:

```
class Item
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

then you can add to your UI like this:

```
listview1.Items.Add(new Item() { Item1 = "1", Item2 = "2", Item3 = "3" });
```

Then bind each column to the string property of your object:

```
<ListView Name="listview1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Employee Information">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item1}"
            Header="Item1" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item2}"
            Header ="Item2" Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Item3}"
            Header="Item3" Width="100"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: `Arrays` will work fine in a `ListView`, It may not be the best option but it will work just as well as any other object.

Comment: Too many attempts later and this simple solution still works! Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Your binding is wrong.

You bind for the first column:

```
{Binding Path=listview1.Items[0]}
```

which will contain {"1", "2", "3"} instead of "1"
because {"1", "2", "3"} is the string-array which you add as first item to the items list.

Better would be

```
{Binding Path=listview1.Items[0][0]}
```

for the first, but this will always bind only your first list item.

But surely you see the fault now?

Maybe if you bind only

```
{Binding Path=listview1.Items}
```

the control knows what to do because the two-dimensional data will fit onto the listview's also two-dimensional data pattern. (But I didn't use this yet and don't know exactly.)

Comment: The binding path on the Columns is relative to the ListViews ItemSource, `{Binding Path=listview1.Items}` will never work. and since ihe Item source is a collection of string[] you only need to access vis the string[] index `{Binding Path=[0]}`